# How can I add gravity to UIButton SWIFT

Tags: swift, uibutton, gravity

So I am trying to add gravity to 4 UIButtons but they are not falling, I added this code to the view did load, I don't why this isn't working well.
Here is the code:

```
//initialize the animator
    var animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view)
    //add gravity
    let gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [redButton!, greenButton!, blueButton!, cameraButton!])
    let direction = CGVectorMake(0.0, 1.0)
    gravity.gravityDirection = direction
    animator.addBehavior(gravity)
```

My buttons are the redButton, greenButton, blueButton, and the cameraButton, also I have applied the direction of the fall but when I run the app they are just static. So is it possible to add gravity to the UIButtons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are declaring your animator locally to the function. When the function returns, the animator is released from memory, and all animation stops (actually `viewDidLoad()` returns so early in the lifecycle that animation never gets started).

Declare it as:

```
var animator: UIDynamicAnimator!
```

at *class* scope

Class scope means put it within the curly braces of the class:

```
class Foo {
    var thisVariableIsAtClassScopeAndPersistsAcrossMethods: Int

    func bar() {
        var thisVariableIsAtLocalScopeAndDisappearsWhenFunctionReturns: String
    }
}
```

And only initialize it in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view)
```

(You cannot initialize it at class scope without `lazy` trickiness, because `self` is not yet available.)

** EDIT FINAL ANSWER **

After chat, we resolved the misunderstood answer and now we have:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var redButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var greenButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var blueButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraButton: UIButton!

    // Declare the animator at class scope so it doesn't get released prematurely.
    var animator: UIDynamicAnimator!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //add gravity
        let gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [redButton, greenButton, blueButton, cameraButton])
        let direction = CGVectorMake(0.0, 1.0)
        gravity.gravityDirection = direction
        animator.addBehavior(gravity)

        // other viewDidLoad setup code to set attributes of buttons
    }
}
```

Comment: When I add the  bang operator it shows me an error to delete it @BaseZen

Comment: It's fine. It just means an implicitly unwrapped Optional. Very common. It compiled and worked in Xcode 6.4/Swift 1.2. You're doing something funny. Do you understand class scope? What exactly does the error say?

Comment: The '!' is not an operator. It's part of the type declaration.

Comment: No I don't get what is the class scope, I am kind of new with swift and programming haha

Comment: So it is just outside the viewDidLoad? And I don't get the "lazy"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84754/discussion-between-pixele9-and-basezen).

Comment: Please ignore my mention of `lazy`...it is too advanced and too fancy for something simple. It *can* be just outside of `viewDidLoad()` but stylistically class scope properties should go near the top.